# How to Pass CSRF token with AJAX request Laravel + Vue.js

Tags: ajax, vue.js, csrf, laravel-5.5

I have a Vue.js component...

```
<template>
    <form method="POST" action="/login">
        <button class="btn btn-primary center-block" @click="$emit('buttonClicked')">
            Login
        </button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    var axios = require('axios');

    Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content');

    export default {
        created: function () {
            axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        },
        props: ['show'],
        name: "login-component",
        methods: {
            close: function () {
                this.$emit('close');
            },
            buttonClicked: function () {
                axios.post('/login', {data: this.data})
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error.message);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My csrf exists in meta:

```
<meta id="token" name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

But it doesn't pass with the Ajax request instead  I get...

> `419 unknown status` and no `_token` in console->`Form Data`

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to use...

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
};
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: If you use `require('axios')` axios is only available in the same scope, it isn't hoisted to `window`. Try your latter attempt but without `window.`. | Also remove the `;`, it is invalid syntax (don't forget to check the console please, it have surely shown errors with both issues).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this `axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
};` but didn't helped

Answer (score 1):

I solved by this way:

```
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
            }
        },
...
```

And inside `<form></form>`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
```